# How to use Lua require() function to access a module before the actual address?

Tags: lua, require

Ex:
I'm on a folder called 'tuna' and want to require a file that is before 'tuna':

Ex: `require "some-file.lua/tuna"`
but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What does *before* a file mean?

Comment: means in the folder that it's holding it.

Comment: you know when you type cd.. in CMD? is like that.

Answer (score 3):

You should learn how Lua searches for files when requiring.

`package.path` is a string that estabilishes where and how it should search for the file you required. It usually looks like this:

```
"/some/path/?.lua; /some/other/path/?.lua; ?.lua;"
```

When you call `require("module")`, Lua takes the first path contained in the string in `package.path` (the paths are separated by semicolons, so the first path would be `/some/path/?.lua`), and replaces the `?` in the string with the string that was passed to require.

So Lua would first search your module at `/some/path/module.lua`.

If it finds that file, then it executes it, otherwise it moves on to the next path: it would search at `/some/other/path/module.lua`, and finally at `module.lua`.

Now if your directory looks like this:

```
Outer_dir = {
    tuna = {
        main.lua,
        tuna.lua
    },
    module.lua
} --didn't know how to represent a tree lol
```

And, if from main.lua you usually access  tuna.lua just typing `require("tuna")`, then your `package.path` must be like `/Outer_dir/tuna/?.lua`. To be sure you can require module.lua, which is "before" tuna.lua, you should either change your `package.path` string to `/Outer_dir/?.lua` (this mean you should use `require("tuna/tuna") to access tuna.lua) or to`/Outer_dir/tuna/?.lua; /Outer_dir/?.lua`so that either`require("tuna")`and`require("module")` will work perfectly.